# finding accumulation points of a topology

Tags: general-topology

in lipshutz book says 
[image]

I don't understand why the point $c$ isn't a limit point of $A$ since the open set $\{c,d\},\{a,c,d\},\{b,c,d,e\},X$ does contain a point of $A$ different from $c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ to be a limit point of $A$, every open set containing $x$ must intersect with $A$ at a point other than $x$, not just one of them. In the above example, the open set $\{c,d\}$ only intersects with $A$ at $c$, so $c$ is not a limit point of $A$